# Is there a way to adjust the DC Voltage

Tags: voltage, dc, power-electronics

I have a source (1) of power which can be adjusted from 1-5 Volts and 40 mAmps.
I have another source (2) of power which delivers a constant 5 Volts and 400 mAmps.

I want to build a circuit which takes source (1) and source (2) as input and deliver a output voltage based on source (1) and amps should be based on source (2).

Input => source (1) [1-5 volts and 40 mA] and source (2) [5 volts and 400 mA]
Output => 1-5 volts (same as what is specified in source 1) and 
          400 mA (same as source 2)

I am new to electronics and would need your help with this.

Comment: This is a rather difficult way to look at it. Could you tell us something else about what you are trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: What you are asking for is simply an amplifier. It's powered by the 5V supply and the input is the variable voltage. It's difficult to get all the way "to the rails", could you tolerate a maximum of 4.2 V? Could you tolerate any difference between input and output voltages?

Answer (score 2):

If you could handle some ~0.6 V voltage drops here and there, then an npn transistor in a common collector configuration should work.  Like [this](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_4/6.html).  You'll want a transistor that can dissipate ~2 watts or so... maybe something in a TO-220 pack and a heat sink.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have:

```
1x Adjustable but low current
1x Fixed volt but high current
```

Are you essentially asking for an "Adjustable with high current" supply?

If so you need an adjustable voltage regulator, but there will be a few limitations. Something like an LM317 will do. It's a three terminal package with Input, Adjust, and Output pins.

If you connect +5V of source[2] to Input, the output will be 1.25V higher than whatever voltage connect to the Adjust pin, i.e. the adjustable output of source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6AbU.png). The LM317 can have 3A pass through it, so the 400mA provided by source[2] will fully available at the output.

HOWEVER, if source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6AbU.png) only drops to 1V minimum, the Output pin will technically never be able to go below 2.25V. Also, the LM317 (as with all regulators) cannot magically have an their Output higher than their Input pin, irrelevant of what voltage Adjust is. On top of that, regulators are not ideal components so you'll never even match the Input voltage.

There are techniques to give you closer to what you need based on the above paragraph, but it may be both out of your current understanding of electronics (no pun intended) and beyond the realm of this forum.

Ultimately, the best you could probably achieve with what you have is an adjustable supply from ~0.3V to ~4.5V, with up to 400mA available.

EDIT:

Here is a schematic of the circuit I built. Some luck is involved with getting two schottky diodes that have just the right forward voltage drop (Vf) - too high and you reach Vout = 1.25V too soon (the right hand 'plateau' on the graph), too low and you saturate Vadj so that it becomes higher than Vin-1.25V (not shown on the graph, but you can see the early-warning signs on the left side of the graph). Essentially you want their combined drop to be as close to 1.25V as you can get. Good luck with that!

[image: 317 schematic with fixed and ajdustable supplies]

Comment: Thank you @chaaarlie2, this is helpful. The ~0.3V to ~4.5V with 400mA is good enough for me. Any more complicated details would not be helpful. 
Another question is if the output is going to be a minimum of 0.3V then can I use a resistor to absorb that voltage, I agree all my output will be  reduced by 0.3V but I can live with that.

Comment: One question I should have asked before quoting the '0.3V' lower limit is: Are source[1] and [2] from the same power supply unit, or two completely independent sources? It occurred to me, after testing it with my bench PSU, that if both sources come from the same box then it's likely that both Grounds are connected. Unfortunately this means the lower limit is 1.25V. On top of that, I've tried a selection of LM317s and the lower-power LM117 (only 100mA, so not so useful) and the upper limit varies between each individual IC; the highest I got was 4.4V with the average around 4.2V.

Comment: I have been trying to test with the LM317, but the results are very different for me:
If I connect 5v to the Input the Output is 4.7v
If I connect 5v to the Input and 3.8v to the Adjust the Output is 4.57v

Based on what you said and looks like you tested it as well.
What ever I provide to the Adj the output ranges from 4.2v to 4.7v

Comment: I will bust out a schematic when I get home. I found that you need to tie the adjust to ground via a small resistor otherwise the output tends to 'float' a little. Should be able to get you an answer within an hour. If you have a continuity tester, could you check if both ground outputs are linked? They probably are, unless you have two separate power supplies (in which case you'll get better results!)

Comment: Hey @chaaarlie thanks a ton for taking time out to draw the diagram. but i am still stuck up... the voltage output from the out pin never goes below 4.5volts (on no load only volt meter connected) or even if i connect a 10k resistor.

Comment: Can u pls share ur email id so that i can send u my circuit diagram...

Comment: Have you got the three pins of the LM317 round the right way?

Comment: Yes i do have the three pins the right way: (Adj, Out, In).

Answer (score -2):

You could convert the 5V-400mA voltage source to a current source by connecting a very high resistance(typically in MegaOhms in series. Let's call this circuit A

Due to the very high impedance value, most of the potential (depending on the greatness of the resistance you've used,) will be retained across this resistance, making it a (approx.) 400mA source.

Next, connect the variable DC voltage source and the circuit A across the output.
This would give you an approximate of the source you are asking for.(1-5V,360-440mA). The greatness in the value in the resistance that you use in circuit A would determine the accuracy of the output values.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. A MegaOhm in series with a 5 V supply gives you a 5 V supply with a 1 MOhm impedance, capable of supplying only a few microAmps.

Comment: @tomnexus A low resistance in parallel will do what you commented. Current does not divide in a series circuit, it divides in parallel circuit; and for voltage it's the opposite.

Comment: @d34df3tu5 Surly you're aware of how resistances add up in a series circuit? 1M-ohm + x is always going to be greater than 1M-ohm, therefore the current through the series circuit will always be less than 5uA (with the OP's 5v supply).

Comment: @d34df3tus the resistors in Series does divide the Voltage and the resistor in Parallel does divide the current, but the resistor in series also absorbs the current. I tried a simple experiment with a 1.5V battery, measure the Voltage its 1.5V and current 20mA, add a resistor in series and the voltage goes to 1.2V but the current is lower as well around 14mA. But thanks for your reply - it got me to learn something new :)